# Attach a file from a directory in email output node

Tags: message-queue, messagebroker

Is there anyway to attach a file from a path or directly in a email output node in IIB ?

I want to attach a file from a local directory as an attachment and send mail with that attachment using the email output node.

Any links or guidance will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FileRead node inline to read a BLOB into the LE. I can't think of way that you can currently avoid bringing the data actually into the message tree though.

It would make a good enhancement request which you could submit here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532